# Звук при падении игрока

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно что бы звук воспроизводился при падении игрока. При использовании этого кода:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    foreach (var contact in collision.contacts)
    {
        var normal = contact.normal;
        if (IsGround(normal))
        {
            _normal = normal;
            scoreJumps = 0;
            if (_rb.velocity.y > -1)
            {
                AudioFall.Play();
                
            }
            Debug.Log(_rb.velocity.y);
            break;
        }
    }
}

private bool IsGround(Vector3 normal)
{
    if (normal.x > 0.5) return false;
    if (normal.z > 0.5) return false;
    if (normal.y < 0.1) return false;

    return true;
}
```

звук падения воспроизводится когда игрок ходит по земле. Я понимаю что при передвижение по неровной поверхности игрок может незаметно подлетать и из-за этого `if (IsGround(normal))` становится истиной, а `_rb.velocity.y` становится больше -1. Но как сделать так что бы на земле звук не воспроизводился. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: теоретически ты можешь проверять скорость по оси Y. если скорость по оси больше некоего уровня при колизии - значит это падение. Если меньше некоего уровня - значит неровности на земле. Попробуй и отпишись

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Флаги делать, конечно, не самая лучшая идея, но и так сойдет.

```
private bool _grounded;

private IEnumerator TryFall(float fallTime)
{
    var startVelocity = _rb.velocity.y;
    while (fallTime > 0)
    {
        if (_rb.velocity.y > startVelocity) yield break;

        fallTime -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (fallTime <= 0)
        {
            _grounded = false;
            Debug.Log("FallStarted");
            yield break;
        }

        startVelocity = _rb.velocity.y;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    foreach (var contact in collision.contacts)
    {
        var normal = contact.normal;
        if (IsGround(normal))
        {
            _normal = normal;

            if (_grounded == false)
            {
                Debug.Log("Fall"); //Проиграть звук
                _grounded = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
    if (_grounded)
    {
        StartCoroutine(TryFall(1f)); // вместо 1f время, через которое должно начаться падение
    }
}
```

Для того, чтобы звук воспроизводился, достаточно изменить только `OnCollisionEnter`, но если нужно, чтобы персонаж считался падающим через какое-то время после начала падения, то `OnCollisionExit` тоже пригодится.

В `OnCollisionEnter` просто меняется флаг `_grounded` на true, соответственно в методе прыжка, если он есть, `_grounded` нужно менять на false, в этом и заключается проблема флагов.

При выходе из коллизии запускается корутина, которая ставит флаг `_grounded` в false, если пройдет определенное время `fallTime` (в секундах) после падения. Если это время не пройдет или скорость не станет ниже, то корутина отключится (надеюсь). Вообще, корутину желательно кэшировать, чтобы не запускать новую, если уже одна запущена.

Comment: Спасибо выручил