# Как сделать условие на отстустиве платформы под ногами

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать условие на то, чтобы если у игрока нету платформы под ногами 5 секунд - выполняется условие. Программирую на c#. Unity2d

Comment: Каждые 5 секунд проверять, есть ли под ногами платформа? При выходе с платформы, запускать корутину, которая будет в течение 5 секунд проверять, не наступил ли игрок на платформу. Если не наступил, то делать то, что вам нужно. В ином случае просто останавливать корутину.

Comment: @KOTlK, почему именно 5 секунд? Если у экшн игра, то ожидание 5 секунд может плохо сказаться на гемплее, могут возникнуть ситуации где пару секунд игрока будет стоя на платформе не считывать её

Comment: @AlemkhanUtepkaliev Вы вопрос прочитали прежде чем писать свой комментарий? `нету платформы под ногами 5 секунд` если бы там было написано 20 секунд, я бы написал 20. Мне кажется, спрашивать нужно не у меня, а у автора вопроса.

Comment: @KOTIK, Извиняюсь, не заметил описание, меня смутило каждые 5 секунд, что не правильно я считаю, но то что Вы описали после поддерживаю, что проверка нужна только после выхода из платформы

Comment: @KOTlK Вашу логику понял, но каким образом проверять, есть ли платформа под ногами?

Comment: А каким образом вы это сейчас проверяете? Вариантов множество: проверять скорость объекта по оси Y, проходиться по коллизиям объекта и проверять нормаль в точке соприкосновения, самый примитивный - создать булевую переменную и, при входе в коллизию, присваивать ей значение true, а при выходе false.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сделайте:

1. Свойство isOnGround(не уверен что оно по назначению мною используется)
   2)Далее сделаете геймобжект у ног объекта и при столкновении с землёй isOnGround равнялся бы true
2. Далее, сделайте методы OnColisionEnter & OnColisionExit в которых при входе будет тру, при выходе фалс
3. Если свойство будет меняться на false, то мы включим таймер
   Смотрите примерную реалезацию

Сам код, возможно там синтаксический ошибки, ибо я писал на телефоне, ну и извините, что нельзя скопировать, если нужно в комментах кину[image: код]

И простая реалезация таймера[image: таймер]

Давайте под итожу, когда объект будет выходить из колизии, вы включите таймер и после каких то значений(счёт в секундах) вы сделаете то что вам нужно: поменяете поле или вызовите метод

Comment: private bool isOnGround{
    get{return isOnGround};
    set
    {if(value == false) StartTimer() };
    
    private void Start() {isOnGround = true;} 
    
    private void OnColisionEnter2D(Collision other) {
        if(other.gameObject.name == "ground")
    {
      isOnGround = true
    } 
    }
    
    private void OnColisionExit2D(Collision other) {
        if(other.gameObject.name == "ground")
    {
      isOnGround = false;

} 
}

Comment: Табуляция правда слетит

Comment: Нельзя такой код новичкам показывать, он же так сделает и будет думать, что это нормально. Проверка по имени объекта вместо нормального TryGetComponent, создание таймера в отдельном геймобжекте вместо использования корутины или таски, все это ужасно и хочется плакать. Если код работает, то это не означает, что он правильный.

Comment: @KOTIK ой да не ной, я же концепцию показал илимя должен делать проекты с оптимизацией выкладывать их на гитхаб и кидать сюда? Я попытался сделать так, чтобы человек понял принцып. Но так оо да, код говно

Comment: @KOTIK не знал, тоесть проверка через try GetComponent менее затратная по ресурсам?

Comment: @KOTIK насчет корутины да, вообще много способ так то.

Comment: Речь не идет об оптимизации. Хороший код будет понятен новичку лучше, чем то, что вы посоветовали. Можно было ему концепцию описать словами. Суть в том, что на вопросы, в которых нет кода, лучше не прикладывать свой код, а объяснять как что сделать и, когда у него уже будут проблемы с реализацией, тогда писать ему нормальное решение. А так, он просто скопипастит код и не будет понимать что куда пхать.

Comment: И кто вам сказал, что GetComponent жуть какая затратная операция? Это стандартный способ получения компонентов, лучше в юнити нет. GetComponent может влиять на производительность только когда вы вызываете его чрезмерно часто и то это будет видно, если у вас тысячи объектов, которые его вызывают.

Comment: Я не говорил этого. Я сам учусь и это был вопрос :)

Comment: @KOTlK Соглашусь, код не наилучший, но однако я взял с него логику и сделал от него рабочий код, а это главное :)

Comment: @Артем Рабочий код - не значит хороший. Если просто скопипастить код сверху, то, теперь надо каждому объекту, который будет землей, присваивать одно имя/тэг/компонент, потому что если они отличаются, то объект будет считаться летящим в воздухе. Да, этот код работает в данный момент, но если нужно будет сделать изменения(а их нужно будет сделать), то придется все переписывать. Нормальный код легко расширять и просто поддерживать. Также, если с самого начала учиться писать нормальный код, то потом не нужно будет переучиваться.

Comment: @Артем Если нужно мое решение, то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1388222/%d0%97%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)  можете посмотреть мой ответ, там ситуация похожа на вашу.